# Spivak Calculus Chapter 5-33d: $\lim_{x \to\infty}\frac{x^2(1+\sin^2(x))}{(x+\sin(x))^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Find the following limit:

33d) $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2(1+\sin^2(x))}{(x+\sin(x))^2}$$

I am 99.9% sure this limit doesn't exist because as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $1+\sin^2(x)$ periodically oscillates between 1 and 2, which means so does the limit.

Is this a trick question or am I losing my mind?

Comment: Approach infinity through two (different) appropriate sequences and appeal to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#In_terms_of_sequences

Comment: I used desmos to graph the function and it seems that the limit don't exist it oscillate between 2 and 1 approximately

Comment: Wolfram alpha agrees with desmos, the limit does not exist: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+to+infinity+of+%28%28x%5E2%281%2Bsin%28x%29%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%2Bsin%28x%29%29%5E2%29

Comment: Divide $N^r$ and $D^r$ by $x^2$ and note that $\frac{\sin x} {x} \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the type of questions like the one you have mentioned the following methodology can be useful:

Assume we are faced with a complex expression:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f_1(x)f_2(x)}{g_1(x)g_2(x)}$$

In the case, the limit is of the form "$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$" the "Go to" attack will be to first identify the "dominant term" in the numerator and divide by it both the denominator and the numerator.

Assuming in our example $f_1(x)\geq f_2(x) \space\forall x>x_0$ we should try to analyse $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f_2(x)}{g_1(x)g_2(x)\cdot f_1(x)^{-1}}$$

In the particular case, we identify $x^2$ as the main term and divide by it, which yields:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\sin^2x}{1+2/x\cdot \sin x +1/x^2 \cdot \sin^2x}$$
Heuristically, now we see why there is no limit when x tends to infinity, the denominator is essentially $1$; however, the numerator oscillates between $[1,2]$.

To prove so rigorously we use Heine definition of the limit:

> $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ if and only if  $\forall a_n\to_{n\to\infty}\infty$  $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=L$

Hence, disproving will equate to producing two series $a_n,b_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) \neq \lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n)$.

For example, we choose the extrema of $\sin$ $$a_n=2\pi n + \pi/2\space,\space b_n=2\pi n $$

Now evaluating the function on both:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\sin^2(a_n)}{1+2/a_n\cdot \sin a_n +1/x^2 \cdot \sin^2a_n}=2$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(b_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\sin^2(b_n)}{1+2/b_n\cdot \sin b_n +1/x^2 \cdot \sin^2b_n}=1$$
Thus no limit exists.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Any ideas what Spivak wanted us to do for this question?